# AttributeError: 'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am facing problem which I cannot solve. I am trying to reproduce code from Kaggle notebook for detecting pneumomia using cnn.

After compiling code i am getting errors like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/pythonProject2/main.py", line 149, in <module>
    validation_data=datagen.flow(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction])
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 963, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1476, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 76, in _standardize_input_data
    data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
AttributeError: 'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Maybe someone go the same error and can help me?
I am using Python 3.6